# Remove and add items in JSON inside AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I have this `JSON`:

```
var videos = [
    {"id":"9854", "time": 56},
    {"id":"7859", "time": 29},
    {"id":"8745", "time": 59}
];
```

I would like to add an item if it isn't there in`JSON` however, remove the item if already there in `JSON`.

Comment: can you explain more what you want to do with example ?

Comment: Add if missing and remove if existing?

Comment: Let me see if I understood. You want to add an item to the json only if the item is not already there otherwise remove the existing item?

Comment: Yes! I just want add in this json one item if it not in array but if I clicked in a buton for example and this item already in array I want to remove.

Comment: i will be better to make two differents functions, one to add, one to remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that to check item exist or not, you will be checking the id propety.

You can achieve the desired result using following function

```
function addDeleteItem(item) {
   var itemExist = false;
   for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
       if(item.id === videos[i].id) { // if item exist
           itemExist = true;
           videos.splice(i,1);  // remove from array
           break;
       }
   }
   if(!itemExist) { // if item does not exist add to array
      videos.push(item);
   }
}
```

Comment: It is not working :( they continue add repeated item in array when I call this function.

Comment: @Deise - It works for me. Check at - http://plnkr.co/edit/siJLZmmfzU9a8GTjQ5ix?p=preview Also, how were you trying to add/delete an item? I need this information to answer your second question

Comment: Now it is working! I was just typing the id value, but now works pretty! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Deise - Good it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to var myObject = JSON.parse(object); it first. Then you can do a check with if/else logic to see if the desired field is present or not. Then you'll need to turn it back into JSON, if necessary with var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myObject);

There's several ways to check if a field is present or not. One of which is to check if(myField === undefined). But, depending on your use, you might need something more specific/robust. I think with this info and a few minutes of light googling you have everything you need.

Basically you have to turn it from a JSON *string* into an actual javascript object. Then, when you're done and if you're sending it somewhere, you need to turn it back into a JSON string. If you don't need to send it somewhere and don't need the JSON notation, you can leave it as an object to do whatever.

Also, a simplifying suggestion: You could make your array an associative array with the id number being the identifier. That way you can just look up array[id] and check immediately if it exists without having to loop. Don't do this if this is the only spot where it makes sense, though. No sense doing a bunch of work for a minor convenience.

Comment: JSON.parse wasn't working inside AngularjS

Comment: It should work fine...  It's just plain javascript. You have something else going on, or you're not dealing with a JSON string.